# ExtJS: create dynamic store \ grid

Tags: extjs, dynamic, proxy, grid, store

Hello Guys im stugeling with an dynamic store i get an data from array 
and create one store but if i try to load the columns and data to my grid i get  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProxy' of undefined"

Controller :

```
  onSqlChange: function (gridPanel, value) {
var me = this;

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '{url action=getSqlDetails}',
    params: {
    fileName: value
    },
    success: function (response) {
    var text = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    //console.log(text);
    var grid = me.mainWindow.grid;
    var columns = text.columns;
    var cols = new Array();
    columns.forEach(function (item) {
        cols.push({
        name: item,
        type: 'string'
        });
    });

    var SqlResult = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: cols,
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '{url action=getSqlDetails}',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data'
        }
        },
    });

    grid.reconfigure({
        columns: columns,
        store: SqlResult
    });
    grid.show();
    }
});
}
```

window.js :

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.UnSqlReader.view.window.Window', {
extend: 'Enlight.app.Window',
alias: 'widget.main-window-view',
height: 700,
width: 1200,
layout: 'fit',
title: '{s name=window_title}SQL Reader{/s}',
initComponent: function () {
var me = this;
me.items = me.getItems();
me.dockedItems = me.createDockedItems();
me.callParent(arguments);
},
createDockedItems: function () {
var me = this;
return [
    {
    width: 185,
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    items: [
        {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        id: 'sqlField',
        editable: false,
        emptyText: 'Select SQL file',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'name',
        store: Ext.create('Shopware.apps.UnSqlReader.store.UnSqlReaderFileList'),
        listeners: {
            change: function (field, newValue) {
            me.fireEvent('onSqlChange', me, newValue);
            }
        }
        }
    ]
    }
];
},
getItems: function () {
var me = this;
me.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    alias: 'widget.view-grid-grid',
    hidden: true,
    columns: [
    ]
});
return [me.grid];
}
```

});

Comment: can we get the data by  accessing `text.data`

Comment: yes it is possible http://i.imgur.com/MO49byU.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling the ajax again we can directly fill the data in store using `text.data` from the response json

```
var SqlResult = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: cols,
        data:text.data
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work get the return http://i.imgur.com/JcmrdSi.png but if i like to use it in a store  var data = text.data;   data: data  get the same error of undefined have i define a  store in a grid i my window js?

Comment: no the grid stills empty :/ as error i get the folowing msg : Uncaught TypeError: a.on is not a function and i cant use define .. i have to create an grid each time onSqlChange