# Jquery/JS: skip N items from siblings. error after holdng key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

When i have a list of divs inside a a div with the class div.

```
<div class="list-group games">
   <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div class="active">item</div>
    <div>item</div>
    <div>item</div>
</div>
```

It is a very long list of 700 items which i want to navigate easy with the page down/up button and the arrow keys to move up/down 1 item.

they function for moving one single item works fine. The pgdown/up function also works when pressing it with a small pause in between. When i hold the pgdown/up button it starts to give me the following error after executing the function about 10 times.

The function that i used

```
function pgDown(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var currentItem = $(".active");
                var itemCount = $(".games").children().length;
                nextItem = currentItem.prevAll().size() - 10;
                if (nextItem < itemCount){
                    currentItem.removeClass('active');
                    currentItem = $(".games div:nth-child("+ nextItem +")").addClass('active');
                    animatedScrollTo(
                        document.body,
                        ($(".active").offset().top) - ($(window).height()/2), 
                        0
                    );
                }
            }
```

The error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
```

it comesfrom this line of code within the function

```
($(".active").offset().top) - ($(window).height()/2),
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

if there is another way to achieve this goal then i am happy to implement it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined

Comment: Perhaps the line of code: `($(".active").offset().top) - ($(window).height()/2)` is being called before the `active` class is being added to the `currentItem` - check if the item exists first.

Comment: Good point. I will try on currentItem variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that at some point there is no element with the "active" class or it is hidden.
You should investigate that.
However this should prevent the error from happening:

> ```
> var activeOffset = $(".active").offset();
>
> if(activeOffset) {
>     animatedScrollTo(
>       document.body,
>       (activeOffset.top) - ($(window).height()/2), 
>       0
>    ); 
> }
> ```

Comment: I have used this check and added it to my move up/down 1 function. Then I call that function with for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) prevItem();. Now the problem has been solved, Thanks to everyone for the help.