# Getting the error "Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: jquery

I have searched the site and found similar questions, but no solution solved my problem. I'm trying to make a div get fixed on top of the screen when I scroll to it. But I keep getting the error:

"(index):59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at (index):59"

```js
    
    //store the element
    var cache = '.faixatrabalho';
           console.log( cache );
    
    //store the initial position of the element
    var vTop = $(cache).offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
      $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    
        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= vTop) {
          // if so, ad the fixed class
          $(cache).addClass('stuck');
        } else {
          // otherwise remove it
          $cache.removeClass('stuck');
        }
      });
    
        </script>
```

```css
    .faixatrabalho {
        padding-top: 20px;
     width: 100vw;
        position: static;
        top: 0px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faixatrabalho">
        
        <div id="trabalhoback" data-scroll-speed="3"></div>
        
     <div class="titulo">Nosso Trabalho</div>
     <div class="texto1">
      <p > Exemple text</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I'm still learning jquery and cannot solve this.

Comment: Are you trying to access a DOM element before the DOM is ready? There's not a lot of context to work on here.

Comment: Have a look at [.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), a second note to your code: `var cache = '.faixatrabalho';` doesn't store the actual element but the selector. If you want to cache the element you can do: `var cache = $('.faixatrabalho');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that `$(cache).offset()` is returning `undefined`, which in jQuery terms generally means that `$(cache)` didn't find anything.

From the layout of your script, it seems that you're likely executing this code right away and the element(s) your looking for may not exist yet (since the document is still loading).  Try executing it after the document has fully loaded.  In jQuery you can accomplish this by wrapping the code in the jQuery function itself, which by default sets it as a handler to the document's `ready` event:

```
$(function () {
    var cache = '.faixatrabalho';
    console.log( cache );

    //store the initial position of the element
    var vTop = $(cache).offset().top - parseFloat($cache.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
});
```

Comment: good. But other points: $cache.css --> $(cache).css plus $cache.removeClass --> $(cache).removeClass