# Navigation Menu Error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever i click on a menu item on my navigation menu, i get the following error message
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined". I checked the browser console and discovered this function causes the error

```js
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
}, 700);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

HTML CODE HERE

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <!-- <meta name="author" content=" studio"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 768px)" href="css/min768.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,700,300|Roboto:400,500,300italic,300|Damion' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" /> -->
  

  <!--Internet Explorer 8 or older doesn't support media query. This script helps ie7 and ie8 to recognize media queries-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

    
</head>
<body>


    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        
        <!-- Begin of  .logo --> 
       <a href="index.php" id="logo"></a>
        <!-- End of .logo  -->
        
        <!-- Begin of .sign --> 
        <ul class="signin">
          <li><span>Already a member?</span><a href="" class='sign'>Signin</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- End of .sign  -->

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        
        <!-- Begin of navigation --> 
        <nav>
          <span>Select page you want<b></b></span>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li class='hide-on-wide'><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
            <!--<li><a href="#results">Results</a></li>-->
            <li><a href="members.php">Members</a></li>
            <li><a href="profiles.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

I have checked other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined) on this site for solutions to this issue but what i have seen does not solve the issue. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is your html? Please add full code.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` doesn't return a valid selector or the selector doesn't match anything

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that code?

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` will probably give you `www.somesite.com`, if anything at all (Why would `body` have an `href` attribute?). And I doubt `$("www.somesite.com")` will select anything in your document, so you won't get any offset from that.

Comment: The code snippet is in a js file "init.js" that handles my website's navigation menu. What happens is that whenever i click on a menu item(eg: about us) the link does not redirect me to the new page instead it throws the error stated above

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. But right now you're requesting the offset of an element that seeks the `href` attribute in your body and html.

I'm guessing you want to get the offset on an anchor.
In that case give your anchor a class and use something like this:

```
    scrollTop: $('.anchor-class').offset().top
```

Comment: i think he clicks on a link in the header and the body is supposed to scroll to that section,see that as wrapped inside a click(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

i tried locally and it works,either your target element has a wrong id or id doesn't exist

i did

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 700);
})
```

with

```
<a href="#asd">ads</a>
```

and a div

```
<div id="asd" style="height:200px"></div>
```