# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined .offset().top-500;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a fresher and new for testing, i get console error in my page when scrolling and it says like

main.js:18

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

```
at main.js:18
at dispatch (jquery-1.9.js:3)
at v.handle (jquery-1.9.js:3)
```

i tried the other solution like changing selector to a variable but the error did not solved, i think i want to search the whole page for correction bu i did not identify here is my page main.js

```
/**
Visionmax v 1.0
Available on ThemeForest - http://themeforest.net/user/nasirwd/portfolio
Author: NasirWd - http://www.nasfactor.com
**/

/*global $:false */
(function(){

  "use strict";
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#nav-sticky").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
/* home page soild features animation*/
$(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event 
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
    var nav=$('.solid-visuals');
    var solid_action = nav.offset().top-500;
    if (windowTop >= solid_action)
    {
        $('.solid-iphone,.solid-imac').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    }

});

  /*smooth scrolling*/

  $(document).ready(function() {

//    $("html").niceScroll();  // The document page (html)

    $("body").niceScroll({touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#000",cursoropacitymax:1,cursorwidth:8,background:"#333",autohidemode:true});

  });

$(function(){var nice=$(":nicescroll").getNiceScroll(0);$("#div1").html($("#div1").html()+' '+nice.version+' ($:'+$().jquery+')')})


  /*home page showcase javascript*/
$(function(){

        $(window).on("resize", function () {

        var etwrapper_height= $('.show-case-visual img').height();
        $('.et-wrapper').height(etwrapper_height);

        var etwrapper_basic_height= $('.folio-visual').height();
        $('.et-wrapper-basic').height(etwrapper_basic_height+100);

        var showcase_hover= $('.show-case-visual img').width();

         $('.show-case-visual').width(showcase_hover);
        $('.showcase-hover').width(showcase_hover-5);

        var $container = $('.masonry-container');
        $container.masonry({
          itemSelector: '.post-unit'
        });

      }).resize();

    /*flicker plugin*/

    $('.flicker').jflickrfeed({
        limit: 6,
        qstrings: {
            /*add your id below*/
            id: '52617155@N08'
        },
        itemTemplate: '<li><a href="{{image_b}}"><img alt="{{title}}" src="{{image_s}}" /></a></li>'
    });

    /*twitter plugin*/
    $('#tweets').tweetable({
        /*add your username below*/
        username: 'envato', 
        time: true,
        rotate: true,
        speed: 4000, 
        limit: 4,
        replies: false,
        position: 'append',
        loading: 'loading...' ,
        failed: "Sorry, twitter is currently unavailable for this user.",
        html5: true
    });


    /*testimonial slider*/
    $('.testi-inner').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            directionNav: false,
            controlNav: true,
            pauseOnHover: true, 
            slideshow: false,
            direction: "horizontal", //Direction of slides
    });

/*Flex blog slider*/

  $('.blog-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
  });

/*Flex slider*/

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });

/* Light Box*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});


/*footer icons*/ 

    $('.head-icon').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('animated tada');
    },function(){
        $(this).removeClass('animated tada');
    });
    });  
})();
```

please help me to get my error solved...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined)

Comment: Why is this tagged with PHP?

Comment: Can you add your html too please?

Answer (score 0):

Check the element exist or not before using top like this.

```
var nav = $('.solid-visuals');
if (nav.length) {
 var solid_action = nav.offset().top-500;
}
```