# Highlight the corresponding menu item of active HTML section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `position: fixed` menu, which elements are section titles from my page. If I am currently in any of the sections, I need to highlight the corresponding item in the menu. Not on clicking menu items - I need it to work when I scroll to sections.

[image]

Code of menu goes here:

```js
<section class="block-product-tabs">
  <div class="block-content">                                                                                                                                                                               
   <div class="block-item">
     <a href="#option-1">
       OPTION 1
     </a>
   </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  <div class="block-item">
    ...
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </section>
```

And example section:

```js
<section class="block-title" data-target-id="option-3">
  <div class="title">Option 3</div>
</section>
```

I tried with jQuery:

```js
    var sections_array = $('section.block-title');
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var window_scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
      $(sections_array).each( function() {
        var el_position = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() - $(window).height();
        if (window_scroll > el_position) {
           console.log($(this).data('target-id'));
        }
      }); 
   });
```

but it works like dominoes, when I am on section of name `Option 1`, ok - console.log gives me `option-1`, but when I am on `Option 2` it gives me `option-2` and all previous sections (because they are under it) - in this case also `option-1`.

Do you know any jQuery trics to deal with it?
Thanks for help.

Comment: did you exactly want like this? https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_theme_company_complete_animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make your code like this. I hope this is the helpful to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lastId,
  topMenu = $(".menu_links"),
  menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
  scrollItems = menuItems.map(function () {
    var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
    if (item.length) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  menuItems.click(function (e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href"),
    offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top + 1;
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 1200);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function () {
      if ($(this).offset().top <= fromTop)
        return this;
    });
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

    if (lastId !== id) {
      lastId = id;
      menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section{
  height: 100vh;
}
.menu_links{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
}
.menu_links li{
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.menu_links li a{
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.menu_links li.active a{
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="menu_links">
    <li class="active"><a href="#section1">section1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">section2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">section3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section4">section4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <section id="section1" style="background-color: pink"></section>
  <section id="section2" style="background-color: red"></section>
  <section id="section3" style="background-color: orange"></section>
  <section id="section4" style="background-color: green"></section>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thank You...

Comment: I have just make edit in my previous code now it change your active class on scroll and on click. please review it once and update me if you have any doubt.

Comment: hello dude, does this ans is helpful to you?

Comment: If you have no time to review answer and give any response to it then why put question here to waste others time...

Comment: Forgive me @KuldipKoradia, I hadn't time to review it. I'm getting on it already!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `active` class (with some active styles) `on click` and remove that just like this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```css
body{
  font-sze:14px;
}

.container{
 max-width:960px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
nav ul li{
  list-style:none;
  float:left;
  padding-right:20px;
}
nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#222;
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:4px 5px;
}
.active{
  background-color:#d90000;
  color:#fff;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:25px;font-weight:bold;texxxt-decoration:none;">
  Visit <a href="https://themeshook.com/" px;target="_blank">My Blog</a>
</div>
  <div class="container">
      <nav class="navecation">
       <ul id="navi">
    <li><a class="menu active"#">About </a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact  </a></li>
         <li><a class="menu" href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="menu" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
    <li><a class="menu" href="http://www.mywebtricks.com/2014/03/add-active-class-to-navigation-menu.html">Read Our Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
 
  
          
           
           
           
           <body>
```

In you case selectors are as follow(because your structure is different)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.block-content .block-item a').click(function(){
    $('.block-item a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

and then `.active` style

```
.active{
  background-color:#d90000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

**Active link on click and window scroll**

> **Note:** you need to change selectors as i mention above

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    
    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");
        
        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');
      
        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
        }, 500, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('#menu-center a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
        else{
            currLink.removeClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.light-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-family:'Droid Sans', serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
#home {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: url(images/home-bg2.png);
}
#portfolio {
    background-image: url(images/portfolio-bg.png);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#about {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#contact {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home"></div>
<div id="portfolio"></div>
<div id="about"></div>
<div id="contact"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Awais, but my problem is that it should work at scrolling the page, not on clicking at menu items :(

Comment: Ops You didn't mention that in your question :(

Comment: @sailormoon Updated my ans please have a look

Comment: I have an error, `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` in on-click, line `'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2`. @Awais

Comment: May be Jquery version (I used `jquery/3.3.1`) or you can have a look here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175094/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-top-of-undefined

Comment: Can it be replaced by something? :( @Awais

Comment: My version is 3.4.1 @Awais

Comment: @sailormoon i didn't get your point in your second last comment? and also update your latest code in question