# How to display a Firestore timestamp field, formatted with date-fns, in a Vue 3 project?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3, date-fns

In a Cloud Firestore document, in a collection titled `reviews`, I have a field titled `createdAt` of `timestamp` type.

I'm trying to display that `createdAt` field in the DOM using the [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) date utility library's  [formatDistanceToNow](https://date-fns.org/v2.25.0/docs/formatDistanceToNow), which returns the distance between the given date and now in words, such as *"less than a minute" ago*.

For example, in a given Firestore document, `createdAt` is of `timestamp` type with the value **11/14/2021 10:49:09 AM**

I am able to access and display the `createdAt` field, as follows:

`<p>{{ review.createdAt }}</p>` results in this in the the DOM: **Timestamp(seconds=1636904949, nanoseconds=271000000)**

`<p>{{ review.createdAt.toDate() }}</p>` results in this in the the DOM: **Sun Nov 14 2021 10:49:09 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)**

I am trying to display the date-fns formatted date as follows:

In the `<template>` section: `<p>{{ computedDateToNow }}</p>`

And in the `<script>` section:

```
const computedDateToNow = computed(() => {
  return formatDistanceToNow(review.createdAt.toDate())
})

console.log(computedDateToNow)
```

And the error I'm getting in the console is

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toDate')
    at ReactiveEffect.eval [as fn] (ReviewDetails.vue?5986:590)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
    at ComputedRefImpl.get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:1087)
    at unref (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:1001)
    at Object.get (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:1004)
    at Proxy.render (ReviewDetails.vue?5986:34)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:756)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4594)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6987)
```

`review.createdAt` and `review.createdAt.toDate()` are displaying just fine in the DOM, between the `<p>` tags.

Why is the `toDate()` method ([link to that in Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate)) causing a problem in `computedDateToNow`?

**UPDATE** Based on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26002671/1459653) that "It is very likely that this javascript function was placed before the actual html was loaded" I added an `if (review.createdAt)` statement and the error goes away, **BUT** `review.createdAt` is still undefined in `console.log(computedDateToNow)`

Here's the code block, with the if statement:

```
const computedDateToNow = computed(() => {
    if (review.createdAt) {
      console.log('begin new console dot log',review.createdAt,'end new console dot log')
      return formatDistanceToNow(review.createdAt.toDate())
    }
      
    })
```

ADDED (in response to @Raffobaffo's request):

```
<script>

import useDocument from '@/composables/useDocument'
import getDocument from '@/composables/getDocument'
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns'

export default {
  props: ['id'],
  components: { },
  setup(props) {
    const { error, document: review } = getDocument('reviews', props.id)

    const { deleteDoc, updateDoc } = useDocument('reviews', props.id)


// BEGIN formatting timestamp

console.log('begin new console dot log',review.createdAt,'end new console dot log')

    const computedDateToNow = computed(() => {
    if (review.createdAt) {
      console.log('begin new console dot log',review.createdAt,'end new console dot log')
      return formatDistanceToNow(review.createdAt.toDate())
    }
      
    })

    console.log(computedDateToNow)
    
// END formatting timestamp



    return { error, review, formatDistanceToNow, computedDateToNow }  
  }
}
</script>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `console.log` the `review.createdAt` within the computed property and check if it's available at that point. For the most part, I think your `review.createAt` date is not available at that time, probably because response from `firestore` is returned after that.

Comment: Thank you @Salvino  The console.log you suggest comes back `undefined`. I'm partly confused because `review.createdAt` displays in the DOM.

Comment: It's difficult to understand this without looking at your code. Please post a minimum reproducible problem, so that we can check and provide you suitable solutions.

Comment: Hi, can you paste the full part of where you define the:
`const computedDateToNow = computed(() => {
  return formatDistanceToNow(review.createdAt.toDate())
})`into the script? Is inside the setup function?

Comment: I just added it. Thank you @Raffobaffo

Answer (score 1):

What I can suggest is to use the [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-date-fns) manager:

In that case, you can use filters directly in your component.

```
// my-component.js
import { dateFilter } from "vue-date-fns";
 
export default {
    filters: {
        date: dateFilter
    }
}

<!-- my-component.vue -->
<template>
    <div>Now: {{ new Date() | date }}</div>
</template>
```

In case you want to continue working with your current code, maybe you can try to debug your `const computeDateToNow`, to see what the values you are getting are.

According to the documentation you shared of [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/), here is an example of console.log:

```
console.log(format(new Date(), "'Today is a' eeee"))
```

Output should be:

```
//=> "Today is a Wednesday"
```

That will help you to validate if the function is being well executed; if not, validate the import of the library.

One recommendation could be to change the data type from **const to var**.
Remember that var can be updated and re-declared, and const not only cannot be redeclared, but also cannot be reassigned.

Comment: Thank you @Jose. I may end up trying the `vue-date-fns` package you suggest, but my hesitation is that I don't understand why, as I state in the original question, both `<p>{{ review.createdAt }}</p>` and `<p>{{ review.createdAt.toDate() }}</p>` result in values in the DOM, but the `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toDate')` error keeps arising in the date-fns function. Respectfully, I can't grow if I'm slathering-on packages instead of learning what's actually wrong. Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

A point is on the computed:
you are returning a value just if the check passes, while a computed property should **always** [return something](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the-purpose-of-vue-return-in-computed-property/74091/4).

So I would rather try with this approach:

```
const computedDateToNow = computed(() => {
if (review.createdAt) {
  console.log('begin new console dot log',review.createdAt,'end new console dot log')
  return formatDistanceToNow(review.createdAt.toDate())
}
  return 'not-available';
})
```

Comment: Thank you @Raffobaffo. I'll try it later today, but it doesn't seem likely to fix the core question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a firestore document containing a timestamp field and in `<template>` calling the `toDate()` function on it.

```html
<p>{{ myDoc.timestamp.toDate() }}</p>
```

It showed me this in console:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'toDate')"

I solved it by adding a property `arrived: false` in the `data(){ return {...} }` function inside `export default`. I fetched the document from firestore inside the `created()` lifecycle hook method and when my document arrived from firestore, inside the `then()` method I set `arrived` to `true`. And in `<template>` i just put a `v-if="arrived"` on the p element:

```html
<p v-if="arrived">{{ myDoc.timestamp.toDate() }}</p>
```