# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getById')

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

I have the following error when I try to access my webpart that I have created: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getById').

The code is the following one:

```
public static async getChannels(groupId: string): Promise<any[]> {

    var channels: any[] = [];

    channels = await graph.teams.getById(groupId).channels.get();

    return channels;
  }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: graph.teams is undefined. Have you tried to using debugger or debug with your browser dev tools?

Comment: Yes, and the error is : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getById') . Just that and nothing else.

Comment: Different situation, but the same "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError.." at https://stackoverflow.com/q/69979593/1459653  No solution yet, but maybe worth keeping an eyeball on. Good luck!